# Generate a unique number without database

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm, numbers, uniqueidentifier

How do I generate a unique number in c# without the database?

(max 17 digits).

EDIT: digits only.

Comment: How unique? Unique for the current process? The machine? The Universe?

Comment: @Malachi: keep in mind that random might produce the same number twice; so it's not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: `Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff)`?

Comment: @Bobby that will fail if you generate more than one number in one time-interval (one interval typically being 1-16ms depending on your timer resolution)

Comment: I just want to know why OP specify "without databse". Is there any inevitable relationship between unique numbers and databases? Do you want to use the generated unique numbers as PKs for a database? Can you please post your original requirement?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yes. But he never specified the closer circumstances of his need...if the generation of such numbers is in such a close loop then I'd do something like `Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + incrementingCounter`.

Comment: For the fun:
MAC_address + DateTime.Now + RandomInt() + Your_Boss_Salary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a look at Twitter's open source [Snowflake project](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/06/announcing-snowflake.html) for inspiration, which solves a similar problem. It's written in Scala, but a simplified version is quite simple to code in C#.

The premise is to get the current timestamp, and bitwise shift it left, leaving the right-hand bits available for a simple sequence number, which is reset to 0 every time the timestamp increments.

By playing around with the bit lengths, and altering the granularity of your timestamp (e.g. decide whether to use seconds or milliseconds), you should be able to produce something which can fit into 17 digits quite simply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GUID, A GUID (Globally unique identifier) is a 128-bit integer that can be used to uniquely identify something.

System.Guid.NewGuid()

Comment: 2^128 = 3.4*10^38 > 10^17 i.e. you're violating the 17 digit requirement